# Barchart using coreplot,iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Am using core plot to draw barchart..I wanna extract values from table view and then display the barchart according to it..is this possible?

Am new to iphone application development..so can anybody pls help me with the code for barcharts..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you get samples in core plot library itself...

Answer (score 0):

You must see core plot's bar chart sample. You just need pass an array of values. If you see example carefully you will came to know yourself.